# Codeblocks problem

Tags: code-blocks

I have installed CodeBlocks 16.01 in my Ubuntu 17.04, but I am facing some problems. Code::Blocks doesn't open a new tab when I select *File* -> *New* -> *Empty file* like in this image: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Zv8aW7D-epY/maxresdefault.jpg where the new tab is named **Untitled1**. This thing happens even if I open multiple scripts at the same time. Can anyone tell how to fix this?

Comment: Are you saying that Code::Blocks doesn't open a new tab when you select *File* -> *New* -> *Empty file* like in this image: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Zv8aW7D-epY/maxresdefault.jpg where the new tab is named **Untitled1**?

Comment: Yes thats exactly my problem. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

From the Code::Blocks menu bar select *View* -> *Hide editor tabs* and if there is a check mark to the left of *Hide editor tabs* click to uncheck it so that the editor tabs will not be hidden.

You may need to close Code::Blocks and reopen it for these changes to take effect.

If that doesn't work open some existing projects from *File* -> *Open* -> browse to project-name.cbp -> open a main.c or main.cpp file in the project tree. Then close Code::Blocks. The next time you open Code::Blocks you can find those projects you opened in the Code::Blocks Start Page (*View* -> *Start Page*). Clicking on the projects links under the **Recent projects** heading on the Start Page will open them in new tabs.

Comment: I've tried that one before, but that didn't help

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu 17.04? Was it a fresh installation or a distribution upgrade? If it was an upgrade maybe the upgrade messed up Code::Blocks's configuration files and you may be able to fix it by `sudo apt purge codeblocks` and then reinstalling Code::Blocks.